# Swap text in XML elements using CSS

Tags: css

I had a XML as shown below. I need to display the text of <given-names> as first and <surname> as second.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="sample.css"?>
<names>
<contributor><name>
<surname>Surname1</surname>
<given-names>Given-names1</given-names>
</name>
<xref><sup>1</sup></xref></contributor>
<contributor><name>
<surname>Surname2</surname>
<given-names>Given-names2</given-names>
</name>
<xref><sup>2</sup></xref></contributor>
</names>
```

For example, I am need of output as shown below:

**OUTPUT**

```
Given-names1 Surname1 1,
Given-names2 Surname2 2
```

I tried the below CSS. I could not able to swap the text in element using CSS. Is there any option? Kindly suggest

CSS tried:

```
sup{vertical-align: super; font-size: 80%;}
contributor:after{content:",";}
contributor:last-child:after{content:"";}
surname{display:inline-block; text-align:right;padding-left:90px;}
given-names{display:inline-block; text-align:left;position:absolute;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to set layout direction to right-to-left. This requires care, since the [`direction` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) is somewhat tricky. In effect, you would brutally override normal directionality rules by setting a *forced* RTL direction for the `name` element and forced LTR direction for its children and parents. Sample CSS code:

```
contributor { display: block; }
given-names { padding-right: 0.25em; }
name { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override; text-align: left; }
contributor, surname, given-names { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: bidi-override; }
contributor:not(:last-child):after { content: ",";}
sup { vertical-align: super; font-size: 80%; }
```

I have assumed, from a combination of the question text and the code in it, that you want the `sup` elements to be rendered with some space before them, in superscript style, and in reduced font size. This part is not essential to the question asked, of course.

There are many different approaches, but no really satisfactory way, since this is not the kind of things CSS has been designed for. The job might be better suited for server-side scripting, separate transformation or document generation programs, or XSLT.